# Use x86 platform in C++ projects

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, platform

My Visual Studio 2012 solution has C# projects, VB.NET projects, C++/CLI projects and C++ projects. Currently, I have three platforms: `x86`, `x64` and `Win32`. When I added `x64`, I noticed it was used by all projects. I'd like to do the same with `x86`, so that I can remove `Win32`.

So I went to Configuration Manager, selected a C++ project and in the platform combo box I only had the options: `Win32`, `x64`, New and Edit. If I selected `New`, the only option  available is `ARM`.

So then I thought of just replacing `Win32` with `x86` in my .vcxproj. Didn't work (it defaulted to `x64`). Then I looked at the .sln file, but couldn't see how x64 manages to work for every project.

Comment: WIN32 is an API not a platform. At least not in same sense that x86 and x86_64 is.

Comment: When in Rome... http://i.imgur.com/pMdq3Y5.png

Comment: "Win32" is the same thing as "x86" (x64). The default names of configurations in Visual Studio are "Win32" (x86 32-bit), "x64" (64-bit), and "ARM" (Windows RT 32-bit).

Comment: I don't know how it's done but I have seen projects with x86 and x64 and no sign of Win32. These are projects with C# and C++. I'm currently looking for an answer, not obvious from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Is any of those projects open source? If so, can you post a link?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The IDEs differ too much to get a common platform name for 32-bit code.  Otherwise reflective of managed code being rather fundamentally different from C++ code.  Managed project platform names can only be AnyCPU, x86, x64.  C++ project platform names can only be Win32, x64 and ARM.  History plays a role, Win32 comes from the early 1990s, back when Windows NT introduced the 32-bit version of the winapi.  Distinguished from the 16-bit version.  There was no real opportunity to ever change it again without risking breaking existing projects.

The x86 platform name for managed projects isn't exactly standard either, that was a mistake in VS2010 that you appear to have inherited.  VS2012 creates new projects with the AnyCPU platform name like old VS versions used to do.  Which pretty accurately describes the true platform for managed code, it runs on any thanks to the jitter.  The name is otherwise irrelevant, only the Project + Properties, Build tab settings matter to force a specific jitter to be used at runtime.  In other words, if you don't force x86 there then your program is still going to run as a 64-bit process, even though the platform name is x86.  That was the VS2010 mistake, it caused a lot of misery.

So you're pretty stuck with this.  It is not a real problem, the IDE can handle the mix just fine.  You already know about the Build + Configuration Manager dialog, it unambiguously shows which platforms are going to be built when you use Build + Build or press F5.

Comment: Okay, so I can't get rid of Win32. Back to the source of this annoyance: is there any way to prevent Win32 from being selected here (see image)?  Because sometimes VS messes up and Win32 gets selected, and weird build errors ensue. http://i.imgur.com/p8AJHOO.png

Comment: But I need that combo to select x86 or x64. And it's really VS, not me. It tends to happen when I unload a project, edit it and reload it (usually do this to call msbuild targets when building is done)

Comment: This makes sense. I was having an issue with an external lib as x86, so I switched it to Win32, and all was well.